# CompressFastText pqkmeans does not install

Tags: python, machine-learning, pip, nlp, fasttext

I would like to use compressfasttext library:
https://github.com/avidale/compress-fasttext

I use this command to install:

```
pip install compress-fasttext[full]
```

I get this pqkmeans error:

```
running install_egg_info   Copying lshash3.egg-info to
build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/lshash3-0.0.8-py3.8.egg-info   
running
install_scripts   
error: invalid command 'bdist_wininst'   [end of
output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely
not a problem with pip. ERROR: Failed building wheel for lshash3
```

I tried python2.7, python3.7, python3.8 with Ubunto 18.0.

For python 2.7, I can pip install the pqkmeans without this error. But compressFast Text library does not work.

For python3.7, 3.8, I get the same error message.

Any clue about this please?

UPDATE:
Just want to add that I made a related issue here in case anybody wants to check:
https://github.com/avidale/compress-fasttext/issues/19

Comment: Note it'd be easier to read your error message if you used code quoting (3 backticks) that preserves lines, as opposed to the run-together blockquoting you've used. When you say "it only works for python2.7", what is the 'it' that's working there? Are the error messages identical no matter which Python version you're using? And, what OS are you using? (It'd help if you edited your question to more clearly include all this info, including the exact sequence of install commands you are trying.)

Comment: Thank you @gojomo.. I edited the question as per your suggestions - I hope that I can get an answer to my question :))

Comment: Thanks! In what way does `compress-fasttext` "not work" on Python 2.7? (If installation otherwise seems to succeed there, & it's an acceptable approach for you otherwise, it might be best to try to solve that problem. But note: you would then have to use older versions of both `compress-fasttext` and `gensim` that support Python-2.7, as per the `compress-fasttext' README.) …

Comment: From the error message, it looks like the real problem is in the install of `lshash3` (not updated since 2017), which is only brought in via what appears to be an undocumented dataset package `texmex-python` used only for optional eval/demo purposes in `pqkmeans`. So, if you can make `pip` simply skip the error, it may get over the problem with no further problems. Will write up some ideas in an potential answer to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, from the error message, it looks like the real problem is in the install of `lshash3` (not updated since 2017), which is only brought in via what appears to be an undocumented dataset package `texmex-python` used only for optional eval/demo purposes in `pqkmeans`.

So, if you can make pip simply skip that dependency, you may get over this error with no other ill effects.

I haven't tested this, but you may want to try, in a fresh Python 3.X virtual environment:

- manually installing all the requirements of `pqkmeans` *except* `texmex-python` - see that project's [`requirements.txt`](https://github.com/DwangoMediaVillage/pqkmeans/blob/129007087021e2ac962dc8f90e85bdce3b87d621/requirements.txt) for the list
- then, install `pqkmeans` with the `pip` `-no-deps` option: `pip install --no-deps pqkmeans`
- if that succeeds, perhaps `pip install compress-fasttext[full]` will then consider `pqkmeans` already present, and not try the problem `texmex-python` & `lshash3` installs, and you're in business
- but if it does still try, you could try manually installing `compress-fastttext[full]`'s unique non-`pqkmeans` [requirements](https://github.com/avidale/compress-fasttext/blob/master/requirements.txt) – really just `gensim` – then `pip install --no-deps compress-fasttext[full]`

The potential end-result would be you'd have everything but the problem packages `texmex-python` and `lshash3`, which you probably don't really need for any of the code you'll be calling.

Good luck, & let me know if any form of this works!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
The solution in the 4th bullet worked for me.
Just want to add that I had to comment texmex_python import from pqkmeans/evaluation.py and its associated code. Also, I had to change np.float to float in pqkmeans/encoder/pq_encoder.py

Comment: Glad it worked! Also note one of the projects involved in the graph-to-the-problem, `pqkmeans`, now has a release that installs without error on latest Python 3.x versions - so you may be able to skip the workaround, & do a simpler install. See:  https://github.com/DwangoMediaVillage/pqkmeans/issues/46#issuecomment-1765691265